# Univocity parsers custom line separator

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I'm reading a CSV from a legacy system that has multi line records separated by `,END`.

I'm trying to use Univocity parsers to parse the CSV line by line where each 'line' runs until ,END.

I have tried using `.setLineSeparator(",END");` but it seems to be limited to 2 chars.

Is there any way to use Univocity to parse with a line separator of more than 2 chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it won't ever be added

https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/307

```
Allow longer line separators than two characters #307

Thanks for the suggestion but it's not going to be implemented: this requires a LOT of changes, added complexity and performance overhead for a corner case that up until now no one has ever needed.

Closing.
```